# Web app to provide analysis of "time-based" data

Tags: web-apps, data-visualization, graphs, math, plotting

With rows like:

```
time | value
p159 | 15
p205 | 22
p211 | 29
p220 | 39
p228 | 47
p235 | 55
p247 | 68
p258 | 78
p303 | 82
p314 | 90
p323 | 95
p325 | 97
p400 | 96
p411 | 94
p528 | 77
p745 | 68
```

..My goal is to *understand* the data.

At a minimum, the app needs to be able to plot the data on a graph. Is there such a webapp that can provide analysis (at least a graph) of such data?

---

[<sub>* alternative input with same values</sub>](https://pastebin.com/U5YSgmQx)